# spring boot @repository bean from Maven dependency not found

Tags: spring-boot, rest, maven, spring-data-mongodb, ioc-container

I'm working on multiple Spring Boot projects using spring-data-mongoDB (w/o JPA). One that contains the common (udc-common) components, repositories and services and others (eg udc-gateway) that use these components. the udc-common library is declared as a maven dependency in the other projects.
(you'll find enclosed the maven detailed configurations at the end of this post)

Environment structure

**udc_common project**

```
udc_common.models
udc_common.repositories
udc_common.services
udc_common.interfaces
```

**udc_gateway project**

```
udc_gateway.controllers
udc_gateway ....

gatewayApplication.java
```

**gateway pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.open_si</groupId>
    <artifactId>udc-common</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

in the udc-gateway project I have a rest controller thats refers to a udc-comm SampleService. When running it I face an error

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in org.open_si.udc_common.services.SampleService required a bean of type 'org.open_si.udc_common.repositories.SampleRepository' that could not be found.
```

the coding organization is :

- the controller (SamplesController) belongs to the **gateway** project
- the service (SampleService) and its repository (SampleRepository)  belong to the **common** project being declared as maven dependency in the gateway project

Obviously the SampleService injection does work but its SampleRepository dependency doesn't. As the common package is an external one I've set the @componentscan accordingly in the gateway app main class

tryed

```
@ComponentScan("org.open_si.udc_common")
```

and

```
@ComponentScan({
        "org.open_si.udc_common.repositories",
        "org.open_si.udc_common.services"
})
```

the SamplesController (**gateway** project) code excerpt related for the SampleService is

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/samples")
public class SamplesController {

    @Autowired
    private SampleService service;
......
```

the SampleService (**common** project) is

```
@Service
@EnableMongoRepositories
public class SampleService {

    @Autowired
    private SampleRepository sr;

    void insert(BaseSampleEntity sample) {
        this.sr.insert(sample);
    }
    public void delete(BaseSampleEntity sample) {
        this.sr.delete(sample);
    }
.....
```

or also tryed

```
@Service
@EnableMongoRepositories
public class SampleService {

    private final SampleRepository sr;

    public SampleService(SampleRepository repository) {
        sr = repository;
    }

    void insert(BaseSampleEntity sample) {
        this.sr.insert(sample);
    }
    public void delete(BaseSampleEntity sample) {
        this.sr.delete(sample);
    }
```

and the SampleRepository (**common** project) is

```
// @Repository (JPA only)
public interface SampleRepository extends MongoRepository<BaseSampleEntity, String> {

    List<BaseSampleEntity> findByNodeUuid(String Uuid, Sort sort, Pageable pageable);

    List<BaseSampleEntity> findByFieldUuid(String Uuid, Sort sort, Pageable pageable);
```

so the raised exception

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in org.open_si.udc_common.services.SampleService required a bean of type 'org.open_si.udc_common.repositories.SampleRepository' that could not be found.
```

leads me thinking that something is wrong in the spring boot IOC process. Any idea ?

thanks in advance for your help.

---

**udc-common pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.open_si</groupId>
    <artifactId>udc-common</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>UDC common</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <description>Common resources for Universal Data Collector</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
<!--                    <source>1.8</source>-->
<!--                    <target>1.8</target>-->
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**udc-gateway pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.open_si</groupId>
    <artifactId>gateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Gateway</name>
    <description>Gateway for UDC project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.open_si</groupId>
            <artifactId>udc-common</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding below annotation in the spring boot main application class (ie. class annotated with SpringBootApplication - GateWayApplication.java)

```
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "org.open_si.udc_common")
@ComponentScan("org.open_si.udc_common.services")
@EntityScan(basePackages ="org.open_si.udc_common.models")
```

Also, as you mentioned you don't need to annotate repository class with @Repository as this is already managed by spring data

**UPDATE:**
@SpringBootApplication itself has ComponentScan annoation embedded to it, so it automatically scans all the classes under all the subdirectories.

Hope you have the directory structure somewhat similar to

```
com.example
--controllers
    -- SamplesController
--service
    -- SampleService
SampleApplication (this is the class that contains @SpringBootApplication & @EnableMongoRepositories)
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Unfortunately after adding @EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "org.open_si.udc_common")  and commenting other @ComponantScan(s) to be consistent i got "Field service in org.open_si.gateway.controllers.SamplesController required a bean of type 'org.open_si.udc_common.services.SampleService' that could not be found. ". The top SampleService is no longer injected. Looks like actually the basePackages in the @EnableMongoRepositories decortor had no effect

Comment: can you add your directory structure pls?

Comment: I updated the post with the directory structure. As stated there's 2 different projects so controllers and common services, repositories and not in the same tree hierarchy. You're right the project structure you mentionned would not need  additional ComponentScan as already taking in account in the SpringApplication and in the project path

Comment: my bad, I though services is also in gateway project. If services is also in common, then we need to explicit add ComponentScan to those packages. Also if your repository uses model from common project, then we need to explicitly add those packages in Entity scan. Updated my answer to include them.

Answer (score 0):

Mb you need to add the Spring Data dependency to Maven

Comment: you're right BFST .. was just to test. More over the @Repository is no needed as SampleRepository is an interface (am I right on this point ?).  I tried without and same issue. Actually I think I'ma facing  an IOC spring problem. Certainly due to my maven / spring configuration (I'm newby ^^). And thanks for your answer

Comment: I just presented a pom.xml excerpt the   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
  </dependency> is declared on both projects (udc-common and udc-gateway)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Kumar V adding

```
@ComponentScan("org.open_si.udc_common.services")
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"org.open_si.udc_common.repositories"})
```

In the gateway.application.java did the trick.

Unfortunately due to the org.open_si.udc_common.services import, I faced a new issue :
when sending a request against the SamplesController I get an HTTP 404 error.
When removing the ComponentScan of udc-common-services (and the reference to the SampleService in the controller) everythink is ok.

Springs does make some stuff under the wood that I don't understand.